# Get azure account information inside virtual machine

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have got a question. Suppose I have a virtual machine running inside my windows azure account.
Now I need to write some c# program(or whatever the language will be) that can give me my account name and virtual machine name on which it is running. Is it possible? If yes then pls tell me how. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only information about Azure environment you can get hold of is whatever Azure REST Management API can provide which implies you have to authenticate first. However, to get the virtual machine name from within the C# app, it's sufficient to use regular .NET fx calls, such as System.Environment.MachineName